# Android: Share plain text using intent (to all messaging apps)

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sms

I'm trying to share some text using an intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");  
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT");
```

and warping with chooser:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sms, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
```

it works! but only for email app.
what I need is a general intent for all messaging app: emails, sms, IM (Whatsapp, Viber, Gmail, SMS...)
tried using `android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW`
and tried using `i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");` nothing helped...

(`"vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"` shared using sms only!)

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Use the code as:

```
    /*Create an ACTION_SEND Intent*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    /*This will be the actual content you wish you share.*/
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
    /*The type of the content is text, obviously.*/
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    /*Applying information Subject and Body.*/
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_subject));
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    /*Fire!*/
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share_using)));
```

Comment: But I didn't understand what make the difference?? Just the outer body String??

Comment: there is no difference. On emulator I got the messaging app to open up but on my phone and tablet, I was asked to choose from the list of apps. Probably its about installing those extra apps on emulator.

Comment: Great answer! Can anyone tell why this doesn't work if you omit `sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");` part?

Comment: How to set a separate text for whatsup only

Comment: Add following snippet in the intent sharingIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

Answer (score 72):

New way of doing this would be using ShareCompat.IntentBuilder like so:

```
// Create and fire off our Intent in one fell swoop
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
        // getActivity() or activity field if within Fragment
        .from(this) 
        // The text that will be shared
        .setText(textToShare)
        // most general text sharing MIME type
        .setType("text/plain") 
        .setStream(uriToContentThatMatchesTheArgumentOfSetType)
        /*
         * [OPTIONAL] Designate a URI to share. Your type that 
         * is set above will have to match the type of data
         * that your designating with this URI. Not sure
         * exactly what happens if you don't do that, but 
         * let's not find out.
         * 
         * For example, to share an image, you'd do the following:
         *     File imageFile = ...;
         *     Uri uriToImage = ...; // Convert the File to URI
         *     Intent shareImage = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
         *       .setType("image/png")
         *       .setStream(uriToImage)
         *       .getIntent();
         */
        .setEmailTo(arrayOfStringEmailAddresses)
        .setEmailTo(singleStringEmailAddress)
        /*
         * [OPTIONAL] Designate the email recipients as an array
         * of Strings or a single String
         */ 
        .setEmailTo(arrayOfStringEmailAddresses)
        .setEmailTo(singleStringEmailAddress)
        /*
         * [OPTIONAL] Designate the email addresses that will be 
         * BCC'd on an email as an array of Strings or a single String
         */ 
        .addEmailBcc(arrayOfStringEmailAddresses)
        .addEmailBcc(singleStringEmailAddress)
        /* 
         * The title of the chooser that the system will show
         * to allow the user to select an app
         */
        .setChooserTitle(yourChooserTitle)
        .startChooser();
```

If you have any more questions about using ShareCompat, I highly recommend [this great article from Ian Lake](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b), an Android Developer Advocate at Google, for a more complete breakdown of the API. As you'll notice, I borrowed some of this example from that article.

If that article doesn't answer all of your questions, there is always the [Javadoc itself for ShareCompat.IntentBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.html) on the Android Developers website. I added more to this example of the API's usage on the basis of [clemantiano's comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps/36188125#comment70305487_36188125)

Comment: In addition to this answer, there are also methods for setting email address recipients like, **setEmailBcc()**, **setEmailCc()** & **setEmailTo()**.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but it is not working perfectly for me, sometimes I get this exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ActivityInfo{67f62c5 com.google.android.apps.hangouts.phone.ShareIntentActivity}

Answer (score 38):

This a great example about share with Intents in Android:

[* Share with Intents in Android](http://thinkandroidsimple.blogspot.com/2014/02/share-with-intents-in-android.html)

```
//Share text:

Intent intent2 = new Intent(); intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent2.setType("text/plain");
intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text here" );  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Share via"));

//via Email:

Intent intent2 = new Intent();
intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent2.setType("message/rfc822");
intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{EMAIL1, EMAIL2});
intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text here" );  
startActivity(intent2);

//Share Files:

//Image:

boolean isPNG = (path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) ? true : false;

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//Set type of file
if(isPNG)
{
    i.setType("image/png");//With png image file or set "image/*" type
}
else
{
    i.setType("image/jpeg");
}

Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));//Absolute Path of image
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);//Uri of image
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
break;

//APK:

File f = new File(path1);
if(f.exists())
{

   Intent intent2 = new Intent();
   intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent2.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");//APk file type  
   intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f) );  
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Share via"));
}
break;
```

Answer (score 14):

> Use below method, just pass the subject and body as arguments of the
>   method

```
public static void shareText(String subject,String body) {
    Intent txtIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    txtIntent .setType("text/plain");
    txtIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    txtIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(txtIntent ,"Share"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is the code that works with both the email or messaging app.
If you share through email then the subject and body both are added.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

                String shareString = Html.fromHtml("Medicine Name:" + medicine_name +
                        "<p>Store Name:" + “store_name “+ "</p>" +
                        "<p>Store Address:" + “store_address” + "</p>")  .toString();
                                      sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Medicine Enquiry");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareString);

                if (sharingIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null)
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No app found on your phone which can perform this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

By Creating an Intent using `ACTION_SEND` you will be able to put extra its type is `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`, the second argument is the text you want to share.
Then by setting the share type as `text/plain`, the Intent service will bring you all apps that support sharing text

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: It just a copy paste from documentation. Please provide more info on doing it that way.

Comment: @apex39 I did so, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Images or binary data:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg"));
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri.toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

or HTML:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the text shared.</p>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

Inside the click listener needed to add this module for sharing text via applications like whatsApp, email like Gmail, Slack..

```
shareOptionClicked.setOnClickListener{
     val shareText = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
     shareText.type = "text/plain"
     val dataToShare = "Message from my application"
     shareText.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject from my application")
     shareText.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataToShare)
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareText, "Share Via"))
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for sharing through sms

```
     String smsBody="Sms Body";
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
     sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
     startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

*100 % Working Code For Gmail Share*

```
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"anyMail@gmail.com"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Any subject if you want");
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
        startActivity(intent);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this,"Gmail App is not installed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```