# How to grab text in which a user input in Java Android Development

Tags: android, text, share

So i'm making this android application using Eclipse and I have created a text field where the user can input a message and send it, the application then shows the user the text they input, how would I allow them to share this message? Here's the code;

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
/**called when user clicks the send button */
public void sendMessage (View view) {
    //do something
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public void shareMessage (View view){
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_share"
    android:onClick="shareMessage" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Oh and yes, I am very inexperienced with this type of stuff, I've just started learning about it today. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possibly related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps

Comment: "how would I allow them to share this message?" How do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message that they entered is stored in the `EditText`

To access the text, you need to do as you did in your SendMessage method. You need to access the EditText element by id, and then get it's text as a string. Your code will look like this to share the string:

```
public void shareMessage (View view){
    final String message = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message)).getText().toString();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```