# How can I fix this code about sending intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, send

I have this code for selecting a textView and copying to clipboard :

```
txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String stringYouExtracted = txt.getText().toString();
int startIndex = txt.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = txt.getSelectionEnd();
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
```

I want put a button that when I press it , sending text enables and runs , I have this code too :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
      sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stringYouExtracted);
      sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
      startActivity(sendIntent);
   }
});
```

But this error appears from `setOnClickListener` (3rd line of `setOnClickListener`):

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable stringYouExtracted inside an inner class defined in a different method

The SDK suggests me to add final before second line of first code. When I do this another error from 5th line of first code appears:

> The final local variable stringYouExtracted cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

and suggests me to remove final from second line of first code that I have added it for solving previous error

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
String stringYouExtracted = txt.getText().toString();
```

Change from

```
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

to

```
final String stringYouExtracted = txt.getText().toString().substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: It has a problem .... when I press the button and choose an application for example viber ,, you see just viber opens and my text that I had selected it from first code doesn't send to viber ...
what can I do ???

Comment: Answer for "How can I fix this code about sending intent?" question is provided i think so. You have to open a new question for the thing mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: excuse me ... I tried to ask another question but  " You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period " appears ........ 
I can ask question 8 hours later ...... can u answer it here please ??? or send your answer to ehsanhanifezade@yahoo.com ..... thank you

Comment: I could .......... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756458/why-doesnt-this-code-send-anything-to-other-applications-it-just-opens-other) ......... please answer it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String value = txt.getText().toString();
int startIndex = txt.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = txt.getSelectionEnd();
final String stringYouExtracted = value.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: I did but this error appears for last line of your code : " Syntax error on token "final", invalid Type "

Comment: sorry i missed the declaration see the edit: final String stringYouExtracted

Comment: you're welcome but It has a problem .... when I press the button and choose an application for example viber ,, you see just viber opens and my text that I had selected it from first code doesn't send to viber ... what can I do ??? please help me

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps  maybe will help you

Comment: It doesn't work too ...... please answer me here : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756458/why-doesnt-this-code-send-anything-to-other-applications-it-just-opens-other)