# Why doesn't this code send anything to other Applications ? It just opens other applications

Tags: android, send

I have this code for selecting a textView and copying to clipboard :

```
txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        int startIndex = txt.getSelectionStart();
        int endIndex = txt.getSelectionEnd();
        final String stringYouExtracted = txt.getText().toString().substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
```

I want put a button that when I press it , sends text that I have selected it in previous code , I have this code too :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
      sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stringYouExtracted);
      sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
      startActivity(sendIntent);
   }
});
```

Every thing is ok but when I press the button and choose other application for example viber ...... viber just opens and This Code Doesn't Sending Anything to viber .... It can just open viber ........... What should I do ????

Comment: your code seems ok, have you tested with other apps different from Viber?

Comment: I tested it now with messaging (default for my mobile) but this code just opened my messaging and didn't send the text that I had selected from first code ............ !!!! please help me

Comment: I think when I select textview in first code ,, I can just choose one option from clipboard_service and this code doesn't allow me to send this textview to second code and then to other applications .... am i right ???????

Comment: I don't think so, but you can test it

Comment: I think the problem is here : ...........sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stringYouExtracted);............. I think stringYouExtracted is wrong here and doesn't send anything from first code to second code ....... please help me ..... I am biginner and I can't fix it