# Can I get all possible instant messaging apps for a specific contact?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, instant-messaging

In an app a user can choose contacts that get sent a message on a specific event.
We want to add support for instant messaging apps like WhatsApp or Threema.

Is it possible to get a list of all messaging apps the contact is known to have?

Additional question:
Can I send a message through those messaging apps without additional button click by the user?

Comment: *Is it possible to get a list of all messaging apps the contact is known to have?*  ... if messaging apps use account API and put this information to the contact's database ... *Can I send a message ...without additional button click by the user?* ... fortunately, mostly no, but it depends on messaging app (fx you can build one which just send a message if you use some Intnet)

Comment: But some apps can for example post to facebook, without the user approving every single post. Does this mean the apps would have to provide a special API

Answer (score 0):

You can use share intent. It will enable you to share through all installed apps.
See this link for help
[Android: Share plain text using intent (to all messaging apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps)