# can anybody tell me how to get share button in action by using onClickListener

Tags: android, share, onclicklistener, whatsapp

I want to share the string on whatsapp with share button on dialog by using oncicklistener.can anybody help me out with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps

Comment: the same way as we share links,I want to share a string which i will get from the user input.

Comment: then take it from the user input then.

Comment: I am taking the input and storing it in a string now i want this string to be shared on whatsapp with a share button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `setOnclickListener`do something like this,

```
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "your string";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your header text");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "your title"));
```

This is basically sending a short message with a subject line , body and a title.

Comment: Do I need to import any library ?

Comment: No. Just use the above code. Accept and upvote the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(contents);
            builder.setTitle("Auto Details");