# Add sms option to Intent.ACTION_SEND choices in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, share

I know that i can send sms with

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

And share with

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

But when i want to share, then i don't have the sms choice.

[image]

Is there a way to include the option of SMS to the Intent.ACTION_SEND?

Comment: Look at this post [Android: Share plain text using intent (to all messaging apps)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I had wrong type 
`sendIntent.setType("text/html");`
When i changed type to 
`sendIntent.setType("text/plain");` then all options are availible.