# How to set a specific text for Whatsup and another text for other apps?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to share a text to all messaging applications from my application

```
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
```

By referring:[Android: Share plain text using intent (to all messaging apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps)

**How to set a specific text for Whatsup and another text for other applications?**

Comment: Do you want a different text when the user selects whatsapp or do you want to only be able to share to whatsapp?

Comment: Different text when user selects whatsapp @David

Answer (score 0):

Try to share with Action.SEND

do this:

```
Intent myIntentForWhatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
myIntentForWhatsapp.setType("text/plain");
myIntentForWhatsapp.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
myIntentForWhatsapp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hallo, this is a msg");
try {
    activity.startActivity(myIntentForWhatsapp);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Whatsapp not installed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the Intent to only open the WhatsApp application then you do the following

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (i == null) {
    }
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    context.startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
}
```