# Exception when trying to share text using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a massage I want the user to share with other apps, so I do the following:

```
String shareBody = "content";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "title"));
```

The problem is that I get an Exception From the system and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong:

```
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project 

configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
09-24 14:25:53.618 24079-24079/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@e2ecc0
09-24 14:25:53.618 24079-24079/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@1417df9
09-24 14:25:53.618 24079-24079/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@1417df9
09-24 14:25:53.868 24079-24177/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
                                                   Process: android:ui, PID: 24079
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getThemeIconWithBG(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3062)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getThemeIconWithBG(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3037)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawableForIconTray(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2933)
                                                       at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.loadIconForResolveInfo(ResolverActivity.java:797)
                                                       at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$LoadIconTask.doInBackground(ResolverActivity.java:2471)
                                                       at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$LoadIconTask.doInBackground(ResolverActivity.java:2459)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It happens only when i do `sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");`. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Edit:

```
String shareBody = "really? I'm sending you a code to our awesome app!\nYour key:"
                                    + " "/* get key*/ + " Get started:" + " https://url";
```

Edit 2: Ok, so apparently it happens only on my Samsung galaxy s7 and not on the pixel. I also notice the log also shows:

```
    09-24 14:48:44.888 31968-31968/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@e2ecc0
09-24 14:48:44.888 31968-31968/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@1417df9
09-24 14:48:44.888 31968-31968/? E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@1417df9
```

Comment: does your share text include some image or drawable ?

Comment: It includes the `\n` char and a url

Comment: Some text with `\n` character and a url

Comment: I did like in this example :https://stackoverflow.com/a/9948549/4369107

Comment: can you add your shareBody and if you want to hide url just add "url" in place of url

Comment: String shareBody = "really? I'm sending you a code to join are awsome app !\nYour key:"
                                        + " "/* key*/ + " Get started:" + " <https:url>";

Comment: Are you doing this in background, as a thread?

Comment: I do this inside an `AlertDialog` positive button

Comment: What is in this line: ResolverActivity.java:797

Comment: I don't know, I can't access to that

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to share text with another apps.

```
private void share() {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String shareBody ="your message";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```