# Android Share details via only selected social media Apps

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I want to share message with only whatsApp ,viber,twitter and gmail apps so write my code as following using `Intent.createChooser` but it doesn't work, even doesn't show error I am calling this method inside fragment...this code worked in my another project there i called this method inside dialog..

```
 public void shareDetails(String message) {

        List<Intent> intentShareList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

        List<ResolveInfo>  resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        try {

            for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resolveInfoList) {
                String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                String name = resInfo.activityInfo.name;

                if (packageName.contains("om.viber.voip") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.plus") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")) {

                    if (name.contains("com.twitter.android.DMActivity")) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    shareIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                    intentShareList.add(shareIntent);
                }
            }
        if (intentShareList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No apps to share !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentShareList.remove(0), "Share Product Details via");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentShareList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Share plain text using intent (to all messaging apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps)

Comment: I want share whatsApp ,viber,twitter and gmail apps only

Answer (score 2):

```
String message = "Text I want to share.";
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

Comment: Dishant i  want share   whatsApp ,viber,twitter and gmail apps only

Answer (score 0):

Your have used `Parcelable` with no size. Try this modified one.

```
public void shareDetails(String message) {
    try {

        List<Intent> intentShareList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        if (!resolveInfoList.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                if (packageName.contains("om.viber.voip") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.plus") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") ||
                        packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")) {
                    targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                    intentShareList.add(targetedShareIntent);
                }

            }


            if (intentShareList.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No apps to share !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentShareList.remove(0), "Share Product Details via");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentShareList.toArray(new Parcelable[intentShareList.size()]));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Babal ,"No apps to share !" toast show always when above apps are installed  but 'intentShareList.size() '  give correct value

Comment: What is the output of intentShareList.size() ?

Comment: size=5 but i installed  whatapp and email apps only in my device