# how i can intent any social media app to my app not just email

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-intentservice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlfxN.png)[My application works fine, but currently when I press the send button it only opens email applications. What if I want it to send messages to applications such as whats app and messenger and social media applications in general I want help because I am really stuck in that part
][2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Share plain text using intent (to all messaging apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948373/android-share-plain-text-using-intent-to-all-messaging-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent is limited by the action SEND_TO (for emails) and the data scheme that uses mailto:

Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9948549/2395376, which answers your question

Comment: thx i found it in your link